# Send TCP Message in Update/Insert/Delete Trigger

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014

I am building a support ticket system using Sql Server 2014, ASP.Net MVC 5, angular JS etc.

As part of the design I want a way for my system to know when a ticket has been updated, deleted, or created.

That way if a user has a ticket open and it is changed while they have it open I can design the system to force them to refresh the ticket before they themselves can make changes to it, to prevent User B from overriding User A's changes they haven't seen.

Ideally, I'd like to design a TCP Protocol server as a Windows Service and be able to connect to it and send it data from table triggers in Sql Server.

Then the application front end would use Javascript and WebSockets.  So the application would be connected to the socket server as well as sql server.  When a user opens a ticket I would send a message that user XXY has Ticket 00X open.  When a change happens in sql server it tells the server Ticket 00X changed.  Then the Socket server tells clients connected to it that are looking at Ticket 00X that it has changed and the javascript prevents a submit until a fresh is done.

But... Can sql server do this at all?  Doesn't appear so.

So I'm wondering if it's posisble to build a plugin for SQL Server to enable support for it like PostgreSQL's Notify feature.

Update:

I've discovered User Defined CLR Functions in SQL Server and have managed to get it working. (C#/.Net Framework)  I made a static class with some static methods like,

```
public static int NotifyTicketUpdate(int ticketID)
{
   //...
}
```

Then I registered it in SQL Server,

```
USE TLCDB;
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyCompanyName_MyDll
FROM 'd:\pathtodll\mydll.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION XYZ_Notify_Ticket_Updated(@input int) RETURNS int
```

AS EXTERNAL NAME MyCompanyName_MyDll.UserDefinedFunctions.NotifyTicketUpdated;

Then to call it in SQL, I just do

```
select dbo.XYZ_Notify_Ticket_Updated(@ticketIDHere);
```

And it all works.  My Static method in c# sends the TCP/IP message to my socket server, the server then checks to see who is looking at that ticket ID and sends them a Ticket_Updated message.  The websocket layer running in client javascript sees it, and locks the ticket for updates/saves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use CLR, which requires a bit of setup.
2. You could create an EXE that you can shell with parameters from an SP.
3. You could implement some standard concurrency. [Optimistic vs Pessimistic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2010/07/16/optimistic-and-pessimistic-concurrency-a-simple-explanation.aspx)

So yes, it's possible.

Comment: Went with the CLR part, I just didn't know what that meant right off the bat.  I made a User Defined function to do it.

When I'm all done I think I will create a UDT that will keep the websocket client tied to a ticket.  E.g. the UDT will be used to store the TicketID and the UDT will ascertain as to which WebSocket clients need notified so that when the row is updated in sql server the update trigger will just call NotifyUpdate on it's UDT.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use Service Broker for handling asynchronous notifications. Not the simplest thing to learn, but lightweight, scalable and already built-in.